# Which JavaScript 2d engine for vertical scrolling game?

Tags: javascript, javascript-engine

I need/want/have to write a simple game. It's basically about a person being dropped at great height, then falling and then he must avoid obstacles and shoot enemies.

I'm not yet quite sure whether the level will be designed with an end or endless and obstacles and enemies will be created randomly. Probably the former.

Now I am searching for a JavaScript engine that is suited for this. I saw plenty engines (box2d, impact, gameQuery, javascript 2d gaming engine and many many more) each seemed to be optimized for certain gaming types (tile based, fps, isometric…).

Which one would you recommend? And why?

Comment: There's not really one single answer to this question. Look through some of the engines and try them out to make a decision.

Comment: yup, that's the impression I got. that's why i asked for recommendations with a reason. Hoped for something like "I used x to create y and I'd suggest you to check that out because it has nice z which you might be interested in!" :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to do a basic sprite based game with collision detection, I would like to recommend [MelonJS](http://www.melonjs.org) for your JS engine and [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/) to build out your levels. From my initial experience it's also pretty easy to hook in Box2D for some of the more complicated computations. Definitely check out the tutorials on the MelonJS site. They will have you up and running in under an hour... You just have to make it vertical.

Melon relies heavily on HTML5 canvas which all newish browsers are happy with. I've been using it recently to build an iPhone game using UIWebView and HTML5 local storage. The idea is I can easily move it over to Facebook, GoogleApps, and Android when I'm done.